# Button click doesn't redirect user to Login page on session timeout in Kendo UI ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, redirect, authentication, kendo-ui

I have a ASP MVC page where when the session is expired needs to redirect to login page. If the user is in a page and session expires and if the user refresh the page, the user gets redirected to login page. However, if the user clicks on button, the page never redirects to login page. I have a custom ActionFilter within each controller action method to check for session and i am using 'RedirectToRouteResult' object to redirect the page, however it only seems to work if the user refreshes the page but not when the button gets clicked.

Here is my custom action filter:

```
public class CustomCheckSessionOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower().Trim();

            //Check Start with 
            if (!actionName.StartsWith("Login") && !actionName.StartsWith("LogOff"))
            {
                var session = HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUserInfo"];

                //Redirects user to login screen if session has timed out
                if (session == null)
                {
                    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "Account",
                        action = "Login",
                        returnUrl = ((HttpRequestWrapper)((HttpContextWrapper)filterContext.HttpContext).Request).Url
                    }));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the sample of action method in Controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Client")]
[CustomCheckSessionOut]
public ActionResult GetOrders([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string orderId)
{
}
```

Any suggestion how i can redirect user to login page if session is expired and if the button is clicked?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Fabien, i used his approach to get it resolved like this:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
            // If we're an ajax request, and doing a 302, then we actually need to do a 401
            if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                Context.Response.Clear();
                Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                Context.Response.StatusDescription = "expiredSession";
            }
        }
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, options) {
    if (xhr != null) {
        if (xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Responded-JSON') != null) {
            var responseHeader = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Responded-JSON'));
            if (responseHeader.status === 401) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                window.location.href = responseHeader.headers.location;
            }
        }

        if (xhr.status === 401 && xhr.statusText === "expiredSession") {
            // Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event
            e.stopPropagation();
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you click the link, and after the page loads, click another link, what happens?

Comment: same thing..it loads the loading image and the loading image disappears after some time.

Comment: What happens when you step through with debugger?  Is the session actually null when you hit that condition?

Comment: i haven't been able to debug it successfully since whenever i clear the session locally (clearing the history in browser), clicking on the button doesn't go to the breakpoint i added. one thing that i have noticed in network tab of chrome or in fiddler too, when i click the button, i see response with 302 for the main action method and another response with 200 which consists of redirect url.  http://imgur.com/WZDH1oh

Comment: I'm confused, is the CustomCheckSessionOut method not being called every time the GetOrders action is evoked?

Comment: it is called. sorry the action method name is GetPurchaseOrders (typo earlier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your controller action is call by a Kendo component, using AJAX. You cannot redirect a page from an AJAX call. Instead of returning a RedirectToRouteResult, you can return an HttpUnauthorizedResult, catch it with you javascript call on client side, and if the status code is 401 - Unauthorized, trigger a page redirect to your login action.

You can update your custom action filter like that to handle both cases :

```
public class CustomCheckSessionOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower().Trim();

        //Check Start with 
        if (!actionName.StartsWith("login") && !actionName.StartsWith("logoff"))
        {
            var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["LoggedInUserInfo"];

            //Redirects user to login screen if session has timed out
            if (session == null)
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    // Indicate to the remote caller that the session has expired and where to redirect
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Location", new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext).Action("Login", "Account"));       
                    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("Session expired");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Redirects user to login screen if session has timed out and request is non AJAX
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "Account",
                        action = "Login",
                        returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url
                    }));
                }                
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

## Edit 1 :

Kendo grid use the DataSource component to read data from remote source, it have an event called "Error", you can use that event to catch your 401 - Session expired error.

### Razor code :

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<YourModel>()
      .Name("GridPOSearch")
      .DataSource(d => d.Ajax()
                        .Read("GetOrders", "YourController")
                        .Events(e => e.Error("error"))))
```

### Javascript code :

```
function error(e) {
    if (e.errorThrown === "Session expired") {
        location.href = e.xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
    }
}
```

If you want to bind to the error event after the widget initilization, you can do it this way :

### Javascript code :

```
function datasource_error(e) {
    if (e.errorThrown === "Session expired") {
        location.href = e.xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
    }
}

$("#GridPOSearch").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.bind("error", datasource_error);
```

You can replace the "Session expired" error message to better fit your need, just don't forget to replace the check in javascript code, has show on the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-error).

## Edit 2 :

You can do it application wide, with jQuery 1.0 and updward, add this code snippet in a javascript file that is loaded on every page (in your _Layout.cshtml) :

```
(function () {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, options) {
        if (xhr.status === 401 && xhr.statusText === "Session expired") {
            // Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event
            e.stopPropagation();
            location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");                
        }
    });
})();
```

I have updated the action filter and kendo javascript code to set the redirect location in a more elegant way.

Comment: Fabien when button is clicked, it will try loading data in Kendo grid. i'm using datasource read on button click to call the Action method.    $('#GridPOSearch').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();  since i am using datasource read to load data, im not sure how to catch HttpUnauthorizedResult in the code.

Comment: updating CustomCheckSessionOutAttribute  filter class didn't throw 401 error message instead it was 200. However i took your concept and updated Global.asax as shown on my original message to get my issue resolved. thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome. If my answer helped you, can you accept it please ? :)